# trouble with neo4j over browser

Tags: neo4j

I have neo4j 3.2.4 installed on a Ubuntu instance. After installing, all I've done to start neo4j is "sudo neo4j console" which directs me to a web interface. Unfortunately, I must connect to the web interface on a different computer which I can do via localhost:7474 or https://localhost:7473. (There is some port forwarding required.) Both get me to the landing page. There I am asked to enter a password (the default one) to connect to the database but I then get the error - "ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver ..."

The only site that suggests a solution is [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/). The suggested solution is to uncomment "dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687" in the neo4j.conf file which I did. I then restarted neo4j but I keep on getting the same error.

FWIW - telnet 127.0.0.1 7687 works so connecting to Bolt seems to be fine.

There is also a Github issue referencing this problem but no specific suggested solutions. (Neo4j - issue 504)

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your exact bug, but we found defects in the recent 3.2.4 release that make it unsuitable for use (browser issues and an issue with concurrent transactions). We recommend downgrading to 3.2.3, and wait for the 3.2.5 release early next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the information InverseFalcon. FWIW I got things to work by switching over to Firefox where I had also set up FoxyProxy. (So not sure if it was Firefox or FoxyProxy that helped - but would a place to start for anyone else having trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to open neo4j web interface, then goto settings -> Network connection section and then check the checkbox that says "Do Not Use Bolt".

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Community edition 3.3.5 on Windows I was getting the same issue as mentioned above, using Chrome. After reading Greg's solution using Firefox, I switched to Internet Explorer and it worked fine.